# Why does pacemaker start on the secondary node instead of the primary?

Tags: linux, resources, pacemaker, corosync

I have two Linux nodes running httpd service.
When I try to add the httpd resource on the primary node, the service starts on the second node instead of starting on the primary.

What am I missing here?

Initial settings:

```
node vpc-storage-primary \
        attributes standby="off"
node vpc-storage-secondary \
        attributes standby="off"
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
        dc-version="1.1.9-55.2-2db99f1" \
        cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \
        expected-quorum-votes="2" \
        stonith-enabled="false" \
        no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
        migration-threshold="2" \
        last-lrm-refresh="1370680015"
rsc_defaults $id="rsc-options" \
        resource-stickiness="100"
```

`crm_mon`:

```
Last updated: Sat Jun  8 09:41:20 2013
Last change: Sat Jun  8 09:28:49 2013 via cibadmin on vpc-storage-primary
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: vpc-storage-primary - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.9-55.2-2db99f1
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
0 Resources configured.


Online: [ vpc-storage-primary vpc-storage-secondary ]
```

The service I would like to add on the primary:

```
crm configure primitive httpd lsb:httpd \
    op monitor interval="30s" timeout="60" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="60" \
    op stop interval="0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting that is missing is the **preferred node**.

You can first add the resource, and configure the preferred node to run it afterwards.

It is recommended to assign a weight below the stickiness of the resource to avoid unwanted downtime in the case of failover.

Check the [pacemaker docs](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-plugin/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/ch06s07.html) for a complete example.